# when to choose container/list over slice at go

Tags: list, go, slice

I have not faced any problem, which can't be solved by slice.

As per the list implementation, Any insertion to list end-up creating a new element struct which wraps the value to `interface{}`
Range is also not supported for iteration of list.
I found some article which says never use `list.List` at production.

Just wondering, why is it there at go source package
[https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/]

Anybody here, used list at production and gained some advantages?

Comment: A container/list might or might not have advantages as opposed to a slice. For _most_ use cases a slice is fine and the better option. container/list might not be used often (same with container/heap) but it was used in earlier versions of Go, it is included to provide a linkes list implementation and it stays there for compatibility reasons and because it might be the right choice. Never believe someone who tell you to literally to "never" do something. It al depends. Always.

Comment: Yes,It is clearly based on requirements.duly noted :)

Answer (score 2):

`list.List` is an implementation of a [Doubly Linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list). Slices are an abstraction over arrays. Slices provide feature-ful arrays that include growing arrays without copying of data, taking "slices" of a slice without reallocation or copying.
It all comes down to the use case. Linked-list is by its nature a growing list of items that does not require copying of data whatsoever. Linked-list is perfect for growing data that has to be traversed in one direction. Arrays/Slices are perfect if the data has to be accessed arbitrarily (from any index without a cursor), or data has to be added and removed from the middle dynamically.

This is a general answer. Bottom-line, 90% of the time you won't **need** `list.List`. Slices suffice.

Comment: In other programming languages,like java, 90% you would choose`Arraylist` is or at python you would prefer `list`. That's why , I wonder ,why not at go?

Comment: @SiddhantaRath exactly, and it provides similar functionality to slices